# Laravel8 multi DB connection

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, laravel-8

I want to do connection postgresql and mysql in my project.

.env file is in below

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=175.145.23.01
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=test_local
DB_USERNAME=birgul_ayaz
DB_PASSWORD=h4CzT*tiCzr21


DB_CONNECTION_SECOND=test
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test_deneme
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=''
```

config/database.php is below

first mysql connection:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'test_deneme'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

second= postgresql connection

```
'pgsql' => [
    'driver' => 'pgsql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'schema' => 'public',
    'sslmode' => 'prefer',
],
```

**when i use connection('test')in Contoller.

```
$dd= DB::connection('test')->table('test_deneme')->user_name;`
```

**page is giving this error**
"SQLSTATE[08006] [7] received invalid response to SSL negotiation: Y (SQL: select * from "bo_session" where "id" = BVx6RU7dtpnIJjfPHRJrVf1RVMO7SR4c81Fkxp9n limit 1)"

**How can is solve this problem ??**

Answer (score 0):

In the .env-file you are defining values for HOST, PORT, USERNAME and so on. In your .env-file you are overwriting the mysql-values with the pgsql-values.

.env

```
...
DB_HOST=175.145.23.01
DB_PORT=5432
...
DB_HOST_SECOND=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_SECOND=3306
...
```

config/database.php

```
'mysql' => [
        ...
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        ...
],

'pgsql' => [
    ...
    'host' => env('DB_HOST_SECOND', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT_SECOND', '5432'),
    ...
],
```

Comment: When i write. Page is giving this error

could not find driver (SQL: select * from `bo_session` where `id` = Sh4oLz4Ix3yrOBcKx5bgq5Yp0AkGSUKh28JRDNP9 limit 1)

Comment: Driver name should be mysql or pgsql , see documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#configuration